# Salesforce org current datetime via rest api

Tags: rest-api

How can I get salesforce org current datetime via rest api.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct field that can be accessed on **Organization** object to get time zone and current date time. How about your try something fancy -

1. Mention Lat and Long on Company Profile.
2. Use google API to get timezone from Lat Long. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/
3. Compare with the timezone of Logged in User.
4. Find the delta in timezone between logged in User and Organisation profile.
5. Get the Current Time in context of logged in User and then add/subtract the delta.

Else if you use an universal user to login using REST API, ensure that his timezone and Organsation timezone is the same.